# Interior room tone for exterior

Tags: sound-effects

Have you ever done that?

I was just looking for a very quiet air ambience for exteriors and found myself trying some air conditioner and ventilation noises, mixed with a lot of discretion. Sincerely, I didn't find the result was bad.

Answer (score 1):

I understand why you might think about going this direction, as a lot of "winds" in libraries are, more often than not, on the turbulent side.  I personally would recommend taking the time to "tone down" some of the harsher sounding winds, rather than using an interior air.  Mix them extremely low and cut together only the calmer breaths between the gusts.  To me, I feel like I would notice the "boxiness" of the air, more closed off and confined.  However, that being said, if it pleases your ears and, more importantly, the clients, then it would be hard to argue against your choices...

Answer (score 0):

I often do this in reverse - where I'll use exterior ambiances on interior scenes (usually traffic).

i think the tricky thing would be to find the right int texture that doesn't have any machinery going on (AC, Fridge etc) and doesn't give it away with reverberation.